# Python - Printing a specific pattern

Tags: python, string-matching

I have three lists and one string variable:

```
var = "http:/domain.com"
directories = ['dir_A', 'dir_B', 'dir_C']
files = ['file_A', 'file_B', 'file_C']
extensions = ['ext_A', 'ext_B']
```

I want to print a pattern EXACTLY like this:

```
http:/domain.com/

http:/domain.com/dir_A/
http:/domain.com/dir_A/file_A.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_A/file_A.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_A/file_B.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_A/file_B.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_A/file_C.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_A/file_C.ext_B

http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_B/
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_B/file_A.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_B/file_A.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_B/file_B.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_B/file_B.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_B/file_C.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_B/file_C.ext_B

http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_B/dir_C/
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_B/dir_C/file_A.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_B/dir_C/file_A.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_B/dir_C/file_B.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_B/dir_C/file_B.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_B/dir_C/file_C.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_B/dir_C/file_C.ext_B

http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_C/
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_C/file_A.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_C/file_A.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_C/file_B.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_C/file_B.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_C/file_C.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_C/file_C.ext_B

http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_C/dir_B/
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_C/dir_B/file_A.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_C/dir_B/file_A.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_C/dir_B/file_B.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_C/dir_B/file_B.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_C/dir_B/file_C.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_C/dir_B/file_C.ext_B
```

This was only for for the case `http:/domain.com/dir_A/...`

And son on for the cases `http:/domain.com/dir_B/...` and `http:/domain.com/dir_C/...`

I have tried myself but I wasn't successful to achieve the required pattern

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Unrelated, but you know it should be a `/` in a URL, right?

Comment: And *two* of them after the `http:`

Comment: @tobias_k thanks bro, i have edited the code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement generating the various permutations of directories yourself, you could use a recursive function.  Once you have the directory, the files and extensions are straightforward.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

var = "http:/domain.com"
directories = ["dir_A", "dir_B", "dir_C"]
files = ["file_A", "file_B", "file_C"]
extensions = ["ext_A", "ext_B"]

root = var + '/'

def combos(dirs):
    if len(dirs) == 1:
        return [dirs[:]]
    else:
        c = []
        for i in range(len(dirs)):
            c.append([dirs[i]])
            c.extend([[dirs[i]] + combo
                      for combo in combos(dirs[:i] + dirs[i+1:])])
        return c


print(root)
for combo in combos(directories):
    prefix = root + ''.join([d + '/' for d in combo])
    print('\n' + prefix)
    for file in files:
        for ext in extensions:
            print(prefix + file + '.' + ext)
```

output:

```
http:/domain.com/

http:/domain.com/dir_A/
http:/domain.com/dir_A/file_A.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_A/file_A.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_A/file_B.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_A/file_B.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_A/file_C.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_A/file_C.ext_B

http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_B/
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_B/file_A.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_B/file_A.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_B/file_B.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_B/file_B.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_B/file_C.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_B/file_C.ext_B

http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_B/dir_C/
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_B/dir_C/file_A.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_B/dir_C/file_A.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_B/dir_C/file_B.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_B/dir_C/file_B.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_B/dir_C/file_C.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_B/dir_C/file_C.ext_B

http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_C/
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_C/file_A.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_C/file_A.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_C/file_B.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_C/file_B.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_C/file_C.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_C/file_C.ext_B

http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_C/dir_B/
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_C/dir_B/file_A.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_C/dir_B/file_A.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_C/dir_B/file_B.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_C/dir_B/file_B.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_C/dir_B/file_C.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_C/dir_B/file_C.ext_B

http:/domain.com/dir_B/
http:/domain.com/dir_B/file_A.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_B/file_A.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_B/file_B.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_B/file_B.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_B/file_C.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_B/file_C.ext_B

http:/domain.com/dir_B/dir_A/
http:/domain.com/dir_B/dir_A/file_A.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_B/dir_A/file_A.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_B/dir_A/file_B.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_B/dir_A/file_B.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_B/dir_A/file_C.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_B/dir_A/file_C.ext_B

http:/domain.com/dir_B/dir_A/dir_C/
http:/domain.com/dir_B/dir_A/dir_C/file_A.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_B/dir_A/dir_C/file_A.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_B/dir_A/dir_C/file_B.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_B/dir_A/dir_C/file_B.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_B/dir_A/dir_C/file_C.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_B/dir_A/dir_C/file_C.ext_B

http:/domain.com/dir_B/dir_C/
http:/domain.com/dir_B/dir_C/file_A.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_B/dir_C/file_A.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_B/dir_C/file_B.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_B/dir_C/file_B.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_B/dir_C/file_C.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_B/dir_C/file_C.ext_B

http:/domain.com/dir_B/dir_C/dir_A/
http:/domain.com/dir_B/dir_C/dir_A/file_A.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_B/dir_C/dir_A/file_A.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_B/dir_C/dir_A/file_B.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_B/dir_C/dir_A/file_B.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_B/dir_C/dir_A/file_C.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_B/dir_C/dir_A/file_C.ext_B

http:/domain.com/dir_C/
http:/domain.com/dir_C/file_A.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_C/file_A.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_C/file_B.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_C/file_B.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_C/file_C.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_C/file_C.ext_B

http:/domain.com/dir_C/dir_A/
http:/domain.com/dir_C/dir_A/file_A.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_C/dir_A/file_A.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_C/dir_A/file_B.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_C/dir_A/file_B.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_C/dir_A/file_C.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_C/dir_A/file_C.ext_B

http:/domain.com/dir_C/dir_A/dir_B/
http:/domain.com/dir_C/dir_A/dir_B/file_A.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_C/dir_A/dir_B/file_A.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_C/dir_A/dir_B/file_B.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_C/dir_A/dir_B/file_B.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_C/dir_A/dir_B/file_C.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_C/dir_A/dir_B/file_C.ext_B

http:/domain.com/dir_C/dir_B/
http:/domain.com/dir_C/dir_B/file_A.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_C/dir_B/file_A.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_C/dir_B/file_B.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_C/dir_B/file_B.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_C/dir_B/file_C.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_C/dir_B/file_C.ext_B

http:/domain.com/dir_C/dir_B/dir_A/
http:/domain.com/dir_C/dir_B/dir_A/file_A.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_C/dir_B/dir_A/file_A.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_C/dir_B/dir_A/file_B.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_C/dir_B/dir_A/file_B.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_C/dir_B/dir_A/file_C.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_C/dir_B/dir_A/file_C.ext_B
```

Comment: Exactly as I want it, Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

You will need `combinations`, `permutations`, and `product` from the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html) module to get all those variations:

```
from itertools import permutations, combinations, product
def combine(dom, dirs, files, exts):
    return ('/'.join((dom, *perm, f"{f}.{e}"))
            for i in range(len(dirs)+1)
            for comb in combinations(dirs, i)
            for perm in permutations(comb)
            for f, e in product(files, exts))
                
for x in combine(var, directories, files, extensions):
    print(x)
```

Output (96 in total; note that I changed all `\` to `/` and changed the domain):

```
http://example.com/file_A.ext_A
...
http://example.com/dir_A/dir_C/file_C.ext_B
...
http://example.com/dir_C/dir_B/dir_A/file_C.ext_B
```

Comment: you don't need all this.  See above.

Comment: Actually, the use of `product` is optional; you could just replace the `for f, e` with two `for` loops...

Comment: @Frank I think you do, if you want to print the variations with more than one directory.

Comment: sure; when I first wrote it it was a three-dimensional product and it was easier to just use itertools.

Comment: Great! this is the answer to problem, thanks again sir :)

Comment: This prints in order of increasing length, though. The question specifies `http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_B/dir_C/` before `http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_C/` for example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want forward slashes, but I coded it as you requested.  You forgot to quote some strings in your prompt.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import itertools

var = "http:/domain.com"
directories = ["dir_A", "dir_B", "dir_C"]
files = ["file_A", "file_B", "file_C"]
extensions = ["ext_A", "ext_B"]

print(var + "/")
print()
for dir in directories:
  print(var + "/" + dir + "/")
  for i in list(itertools.product(files, extensions)):
    print("%s/%s/%s.%s" % (var, dir, i[0], i[1]))
  print()
```

Comment: An earlier version of your answer had backslashes - and lots of them. In that situation, it is tidier to use a raw string (prefixed with `r`) rather than doubling all the backslashes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, sir but it's not exactly as I want it since it doesn't print out this snippet

Comment: sure thing.  Please accept if that's the one that works for you :).

Comment: @alaniwi yeah, that's a great point; I was just trying to crank something out.  I would clean up all the print statements and strings if putting more time in.

Comment: http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_B/
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_B/file_A.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_B/file_A.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_B/file_B.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_B/file_B.ext_B
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_B/file_C.ext_A
http:/domain.com/dir_A/dir_B/file_C.ext_B

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows:

```
from itertools import product

var = "http:\\\\domain.com"
directories = ["dir_A", "dir_B", "dir_C"]
files = ["file_A", "file_B", "file_C"]
extensions = ["ext_A", "ext_B"]

nestDir = ""
for directory in directories:
    nestDir = nestDir + "\\\\" + directory
    for file, ext in product(files, extensions):
        print(var + nestDir + "\\\\" + file + "." + ext)
```

Comment: This does not produce entries with `dirA/dirC/dirB` or `dirB/dirA` etc.

Comment: Thank you sir but this is only for "dir_A" how can i repeat this process for the element "dir_B" and "dir_C" as well ?

Comment: Yes, when I originally saw the question, I thought this was the pattern being followed